# Does the order of function parameters matter in regards to variable types?

Tags: solidity

e.g: which of the two are worse?

```
// A
foo(uint8, uint8, bool, bool)

// B
foo(uint8, bool, bool, uint8)
```

Should arguments be optimised and packed properly like structs (A)? Or does it not matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no inherent benefit as the function parameters are not packed by the compiler.

See https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.17/internals/layout_in_storage.html#storage-inplace-encoding